# Border of Canvas should be Beziercurve / LCARS Canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, border, win-universal-app

I'm trying to program a security System using a Raspberry Pi and new Windows Universal App Platform (so I'm using Windows IoT). 
This security System should look like the LCARS OS, used in the "younger" Star Trek Spaceships. I had no Problem designing the Buttons etc. but if you know LCARS, you know that there are theese so called "elbows". I thought it would be a good idea to use a canvas for that.

I tried to give the canvas a border that is drawn with a beziercurve but that did not work.

Actually I have no idea how I could resolve the problem. Is there anybody who may help (or has a complete different /better idea)?

I'm using C# with XAML for developing (Blank Windows Universal App Template).

Comment: This actually sounds like an interesting project. If you want a hand let me know, I can take care of everything you're talking about if not just to add it to my portfolio. Otherwise, you're likely going to need to do a fair amount of custom path geometry to create all the odd shapes you're referring to.

Comment: I'd be happy about any help I get. But please recognize that I'm not able to offer you any compensation. I wanted to do this as a private Project for my own. And Maybe, If there are any public interests, to put the Code on Github.

Comment: Haha no worries, if I ever offer someone help then compensation is never a consideration. If it was then it's work, not help lol. Just sounds kind of cool to make. :)

Comment: Allright the, I checked in what I have so far into my GitHub: [link](https://github.com/crstmkt/CSRedAlert)
Please don't wonder. It's actually all experimental Code based on an IoT example provided by Microsoft.

Comment: No worries, I probably won't have time to even look until probably sunday. If you want you could just give me your email so you don't share public if you don't want, and chances are I may know the guy that made the example you're using

Comment: Okay, you can contanct me via drummercrm@outlook.de  
looking Forward to hear from you.